# taking text from title attribute and adding it into a div in jquery

Tags: jquery, attributes

Basically i'm trying to grap the text from the title attribute in a link and show it in a paragaph in another div when a user hovers of the item, and then hide it when the user moves away. so far what i've got is

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.showText = function() {
        $(this).hover(
            function() {
                $(this)
                    .data('title', $(this).attr('title'))
                    .removeAttr('title')
        .appendTo(".itemDecription p");
            }, 
            function() {
                $(this).attr('title', $("this").data('title'));
            }
        );
    }
})(jQuery);

//call the plugin
$(function(){
$('.wrapper ul li a').showText();

});
```

I got the code from somewhere else on stackoverflow, but i just can't seem to get it to work, and help would be much appriciated.

Comment: Please define *just can't seem to get it to work*. Do you get any error? I don't see any reason for removing the title attribute from the link. Why do you do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure about the `data` stuff and why you want to remove the `title` attribute from the element (I see no reason to do it) but you probably want:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.showText = function() {
        this.each(function() {
            $(this).hover(
               function() {        
                   $(".itemDecription p").text($(this).attr('title'));
                   $(this).data('title', $(this).attr('title')).removeAttr('title');
               }, 
               function() {
                   $(".itemDecription p").empty();
                   $(this).attr('title', $(this).data('title'));
               }
            );
        });
        return this;
    }
})(jQuery);
```

It is important that you use `each()` because the selector might select multiple `a` elements (maybe this is reason why it does not work).

So also [How to develop a jQuery plugin](http://www.sitepoint.com/blogs/2009/07/22/how-to-develop-a-jquery-plugin/)

Answer (score 0):

```
.appendTo("itemDecription p"); // error here... it's either '.itemDecription p' or '#itemDecription p'
```

**edit**

[I modified your codes...](http://jsbin.com/eniji/edit) please look...

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply,I've corrected my error, how ever it still doesn't work.

Comment: From what i can see aswell is that its not replacing the text back into the title attr after the hover